# Can't connect to Postgres database from IDE

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, intellij-idea

I created a container with Postgres in Docker, but when I try to connect to the database, it tells me that the password is wrong, although I enter it correctly.

Error from IDE: **[28P01] FATAL: password authentication failed for user 'testuser'**

The command I use to lift the container: **docker run -d --hostname test --name test -p 5401:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=testuser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_DB=testdb -v /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data --restart=unless-stopped postgres:14.5**

Container console message:

```
2024-03-11 02:34:48 2024-03-10 23:34:48.546 UTC [71] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testuser"
2024-03-11 02:34:48 2024-03-10 23:34:48.546 UTC [71] DETAIL:  Role "testuser" does not exist.
2024-03-11 02:34:48     Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

I am using Windows 11. Docker version 4.22.0. Maybe this information will be useful.

I tried to somehow interact with the container from the console, but it keeps saying my role doesn't exist, not even the "postgres" role, even though pgAdmin has it.

Comment: "*it keeps saying my role doesn't exist, not even the "postgres" role, even though pgAdmin has it*" Would you show us what you're looking at in pgAdmin? Are you *sure* pgAdmin is connected to the right database?

Comment: You might want to show what you are doing to connect to the DB?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> it tells me that the password is wrong

It says password authentication failed *because your user does not exist*.

Let's look at it with the timestamps removed.

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testuser"
DETAIL:  Role "testuser" does not exist.
```

You need to create that role.